# Require dependency only when backbone view is loaded

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs, amd

I am using Backbone with Layout Manager and RequireJS.

View1 depends on 2 dependencies as can be seen below.
The application also has a similar view
named View2, which depends only on 'jquery.fileupload', unlike View1, which has 2 deps.

```
define(['jquery.fileupload', 'jquery.fileupload-ui'], function (dep1, dep2) {

    var View1 = Backbone.View.extend({

        ...

    });

    return View1;

});
```

The problem is that 'jquery.fileupload-ui' (second dependency) seems to be loaded/evaluated by requireJS even if I don't visit a view that depends on it and that causes some plugin errors (I am using basic fileupload plugin in one view, and extended fileupload plugin in another view). It looks like define() pre-loads modules right away.

How can I avoid loading the second dependency at app initialization and load it only inside my view?
I think I could nest require() call into define for View1,
but I am not sure how then I can return a value if calls are nested.

Comment: Require.js should load the view lazily, so if you don't create an instance of View1 by the time you use View2 you shouldn't have problems. You'd better focus on the plugin errors you get and resolve it however - maybe you can post part of it here?

Answer (score 0):

Any time you module load the view1 module, 'jquery.fileupload-ui' will be loaded.  If you only need this module in certain cases when you module load view1, you could have view1 require() in 'jquery.fileupload-ui' only if a certain code path is reached.

You can do this by adding a `require(['jquery.fileupload-ui'], function(jqui){...});` in the specific method within view1 where you need the library.

I am not sure if this answers your question, but I think it may.